# Wait for threads from loaded dll to finish in windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

I have a thread that runs in a dll that I dynamic link with in my main app. Is there a way to wait for all threads in an .exe (including it's loaded dll's) without knowing the thread handle? Windows 7 x64, vc++
The thread is a function that does some processing on a certain file, it is not expected to return anything, it works upon a global class that is modified in certain stages of the thread completion. The thread function calls upon other functions .
I want to wait until the last line of the function is executed.

Comment: You need to clarify. "wait for thread" means wait for thread completion. A thread started from DLL might attempt to wait for all other process thread, but reality is that it is a deadlock. You need to step back and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is events an alternative? how do they work across dll's ?

Comment: My point is that your question at all does not make sense. Waiting for threads your own thread is likely to lock dead. So your explaining why you need this might get you real alternative.

Comment: If I understand _"wait for all threads in an exe including loaded dlls"_ correctly, this is equivalent to the process terminating. That's what happens when the last thread exits. Which means you can simply wait on the process handle.

Comment: @Roman R. I understand what you, but when main reaches its end I don't know if the the thread from the dll has completed execution, if main ends all threads from the process end right?  It behaves weird, sometimes it does, sometimes not ... I can t explain why .. So i thought that the DLL Thread does not reach the end of its execution until main ends.

Comment: I suppose you are approaching the problem from the wrong end. You should rather investigate what exactly "behaves weird". There is a set of typical issues related to crashing on termination, e.g. use of deallocated memory. This is where you should rather sort it out instead. Putting a thread sync workaround might help or might not help - you are making a shot in the dark.

Comment: thank you Roman R, I 've solved it, you were right, it is too subjective to my code post it, the general question remains and it has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never did this myself, but you could probably

1. create a snapshot using [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. then enumerate the threads using [`Thread32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Thread32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. for each thread ID, use [`OpenThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to aquire a handle. Make sure that you open the thread with the [`SYNCHRONIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  privilege so that you can, at last
4. pass all thread handles to [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wait for all of them to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, assuming that all you want is to stop the main() function from running but not exit the process until any other threads are complete, is to call

```
ExitThread(GetCurrentThread());
```

from within main().  If you don't call `ExitProcess`, either explicitly or by returning from main(), Windows will not exit until the last thread exits.

Note that there is a major problem with doing this, no matter how you approach it: if one of the Windows APIs you use has launched a thread that isn't going to exit, your application won't exit either.

The proper solution is for the DLL itself to contain a shutdown function that waits for its own threads to exit if necessary.